# How can I add names/title/values (months) to Y axis for my line chart?

Tags: swift, charts, linechart

I am trying to simple line chart. Chart is coming fine and I want to add values/names for every point of x and y axis.

See the following image, this is is comming , but I want to add/show values in x and y axis.

[image]

For example: Check in my example code, I mentioned months and unitSold values.

in X axis I wants to show months names and Y axis and I wants to show some unit sold values.

How can I do or show values in x and y axis?

```
import UIKit
import Charts


class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
   // var chartDataBeanArray = [ChartDataBean]()

    let months = ["Jan" , "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "August", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    let unitsSold = [24.0,43.0,56.0,23.0,56.0,68.0,48.0,120.0,41.0,34.0,55.9,12.0,34.0]

    @IBOutlet weak var chartViewOutlet: LineChartView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        setChart(months, values: unitsSold)

    }


     func setChart(_ dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

        print(values)
        print(dataPoints)
        chartViewOutlet.noDataText = "No data available!"

        for i in 0..<values.count {
            print("chart point : \(values[i])")
            let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let line1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "Units Consumed")
        line1.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
        line1.mode = .cubicBezier
        line1.cubicIntensity = 0.2

        let gradient = getGradientFilling()
        line1.fill = Fill.fillWithLinearGradient(gradient, angle: 90.0)
        line1.drawFilledEnabled = true


        let data = LineChartData()
        data.addDataSet(line1)
        chartViewOutlet.data = data
        chartViewOutlet.setScaleEnabled(false)
        chartViewOutlet.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.5)
        chartViewOutlet.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
        chartViewOutlet.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        chartViewOutlet.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        chartViewOutlet.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        chartViewOutlet.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        chartViewOutlet.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        chartViewOutlet.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        chartViewOutlet.legend.enabled = false
        chartViewOutlet.xAxis.enabled = false
        chartViewOutlet.leftAxis.enabled = false
        chartViewOutlet.rightAxis.enabled = false
        chartViewOutlet.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false


    }

    /// Creating gradient for filling space under the line chart
    private func getGradientFilling() -> CGGradient {
        // Setting fill gradient color
        let coloTop = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 133/255, blue: 220/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 155/255, blue: 210/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        // Colors of the gradient
        let gradientColors = [coloTop, colorBottom] as CFArray
        // Positioning of the gradient
        let colorLocations: [CGFloat] = [0.7, 0.0]
        // Gradient Object
        return CGGradient.init(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: gradientColors, locations: colorLocations)!
    }


}
```

**EDIT** : After adding following code suggested by @marc

```
chartViewOutlet.xAxis.enabled = true
chartViewOutlet.leftAxis.enabled = true
```

this is now showing chart.

[image]

**Now I wants to show months values in bottom (x axis)...how to show it?**

You can find source code here if you want to check it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vkPqktZ3mX3q9f75-bihVYeublwc2dXE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: try setting `chartViewOutlet.xAxis.enabled = true` and `chartViewOutlet.leftAxis.enabled = true` and `chartViewOutlet.rightAxis.enabled = true`

Comment: values are coming in last and right side. Thank you . But I need to show/enable x axis and wants to show months data/values on it. Currently y axis is showing with unitsSold data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following code in your project.

```
 func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    for i in 0 ..< dataPoints.count {
        dataEntries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i]))
    }

    let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "Units Consumed")
    lineChartDataSet.axisDependency = .left
    lineChartDataSet.setColor(UIColor.black)
    lineChartDataSet.setCircleColor(UIColor.black) // our circle will be dark red
    lineChartDataSet.lineWidth = 1.0
    lineChartDataSet.circleRadius = 3.0 // the radius of the node circle
    lineChartDataSet.fillAlpha = 1
    lineChartDataSet.fillColor = UIColor.black
    lineChartDataSet.highlightColor = UIColor.white
    lineChartDataSet.drawCircleHoleEnabled = true

    var dataSets = [LineChartDataSet]()
    dataSets.append(lineChartDataSet)


    let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
    chartViewOutlet.data = lineChartData
    chartViewOutlet.rightAxis.enabled = false
    chartViewOutlet.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    chartViewOutlet.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    chartViewOutlet.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: dataPoints)
    chartViewOutlet.legend.enabled = true
}
```

Output:

[image]

This works 100%. Try it.

Comment: thank you. It's working. I did some little changes and implemented according to my requirement